# Как открыть файл .svg в delphi xe8

Tags: delphi, svg, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

В Delphi XE8 есть компонент по работе с векторной графикой (TPath).
Как прочитать векторный файл *.svg используя FireMonkey?

Вот пример содержимого файла https://yastatic.net/weather/i/icons/svg/ovc.svg

```
<svg enable-background="new 0 0 30 30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M5.6 22c-1.8 0-3.3-1.6-3.3-3.4 0-1.8 1.5-3.3 3.3-3.3h.2c.6-1.9 2.2-3.2 4.2-3.2.1 0 .2 0 .4.1.9-2.6 3.4-4.6 6.3-4.6 3.3 0 6.1 2.4 6.6 5.6.5-.1.9-.2 1.3-.2
2.5 0 4.5 2 4.5 4.5s-2 4.5-4.5 4.5h-19zm17.73-7c-.767.343-.96.367-1.16.267-.2-.1-.215-.267-.4-1.067-.452-2.934-2.27-4.8-4.97-4.8-2.6 0-4.8 2.1-4.8 4.6 0 .4-.1.5-.5.2-.4-.2-.9-.4-1.4-.4-1.4 0-2.6 1.1-2.7
2.8 0 .4.1.8 0 .9-.1.1-.3-.1-.8-.3-.517-.2-.8-.2-1-.2-.8 0-1.5.7-1.5 1.5S4.8 20 5.6 20h19c1.4 0 2.6-1.2 2.6-2.6 0-1.4-1.1-2.6-2.6-2.6-.33 0-.882.027-1.27.2z" fill="#006ED4" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg>
```

Пытаюсь в ставить его в *Data* - вообще ни чего не происходит.
Если вставить только содержимое *path*, то выдает ошибку

> '-3.2.1' is not a valid floating point value.

Что делать, как мне прочесть векторный файл не используя дополнительные скачиваемые, подключаемые объекты?

Comment: *Если вопрос решен, выберите ответ как принятый. Что бы другие тоже завтра пользовались.*

Answer (score 1):

попробуй

```
m5.6,22c-1.8,0 -3.3,-1.6 -3.3,-3.4c0,-1.8 1.5,-3.3 3.3,-3.3h0.2c0.6,-1.9 2.2,-3.2 4.2,-3.2c0.1,0 0.2,0 0.4,0.1c0.9,-2.6 3.4,-4.6 6.3,-4.6c3.3,0 6.1,2.4 6.6,5.6c0.5,-0.1 0.9,-0.2 1.3,-0.2c2.5,0 4.5,2 4.5,4.5s-2,4.5 -4.5,4.5h-19l0,0zm17.73,-7c-0.767,0.343 -0.96,0.367 -1.16,0.267c-0.2,-0.1 -0.215,-0.267 -0.4,-1.067c-0.452,-2.934 -2.27,-4.8 -4.97,-4.8c-2.6,0 -4.8,2.1 -4.8,4.6c0,0.4 -0.1,0.5 -0.5,0.2c-0.4,-0.2 -0.9,-0.4 -1.4,-0.4c-1.4,0 -2.6,1.1 -2.7,2.8c0,0.4 0.1,0.8 0,0.9c-0.1,0.1 -0.3,-0.1 -0.8,-0.3c-0.517,-0.2 -0.8,-0.2 -1,-0.2c-0.8,0 -1.5,0.7 -1.5,1.5s0.7,1.5 1.5,1.5h19c1.4,0 2.6,-1.2 2.6,-2.6c0,-1.4 -1.1,-2.6 -2.6,-2.6c-0.33,0 -0.882,0.027 -1.27,0.2z
```

[http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1771/trunk/editor/svg-editor.html) перевел формат который ты дал на формат, который понимает Delphi

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало! Но вопрос остается, как теперь сделать такой перевод для Delphi? Что бы он сам переводил в ему понятный формат

Comment: Думаю нужно формат svg прочитать. Там как я понял есть архивирование файла. Может из за этого. Как бы Delphi использует не архивированный формат.   А для перевода лучше открыть новый вопрос